# find last match in column using built in functions in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have an excel workbook with multiple instances of the same client ID.  So, a client can appear more than once in the list.  I would like to find the last (closest to the bottom) instance of the client ID so i can then look along that same row for additional information.  VLOOKUP shows the fist instance, I need the last.

So, how do I find the last instance of a given client ID using built in functions?  I'd rather not write a macro to do this.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Suppose you want to find last instance of id `"id_1"` in range `A2:A8` and return corresponding value from range `B2:B8`, then use:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(A2:A8="id_1"),B2:B8)
```

[image]

---

If you want to return *index* of last intance of id `"id_1"` in range `A2:A8`, use:

```
=MATCH(2,1/(A2:A8="id_1"))
```

with array entry (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>).

If you want to return *row number* of last intance of id `"id_1"`, use:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(A2:A8="id_1"),ROW(A2:A8))
```

This syntax is a special trick: `(A2:A8="id_1")` evaluates to `{TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,...}`. Next, assuming that `TRUE=1` and `FALSE=0`, the part `1/{TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,...}` gives you `{1,#DIV0!,#DIV0!,1,..}`.

To return last number in resulting array `lookup_value` should be greater than any value in lookup_array (`{1,#DIV0!,#DIV0!,1,..}` in our case). Since array contains only `1` or `#DIV0!`, we can take `2` as `lookup_value`, because it's always greater than `1`.

Comment: I'm getting it to work, but I have no idea why.  in my formula wizzard, the `2` is called `Lookup Value`.  What is the `2` for in your formula?  Also, why the `1/...` for the range?

Comment: it is a special trick..`(A2:A8="id_1")` evaluates to `{TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,...}`, next, assuming that `TRUE`=`1` and `FALSE`=`0`, part `1/{TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,...}` gives you `{1,#DIV0!,#DIV0!,1,..}`. To return _last number_ in resulting array lookup_value should be greater than any value in lookup_array (`{1,#DIV0!,#DIV0!,1,..}` in our case), since array contains only `1` or `#DIV0!`, we can take `2` as lookup_value, because it's always greater than `1`.

Comment: wow!  Thanks very much, but I still don't really understand. Is there a reference you can point me to?  Also, will this work in VLOOKUP?

Comment: in general this formula based on `If the LOOKUP can not find an exact match, it chooses the largest value in the array that is less than or equal to the value.` (from [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/lookup.php)). You can also use this trick with `MATCH` formula (as in my example above), however it requires array entry, presonally I prefer `LOOKUP`

Comment: About `Vlookup` - no, you can't do it, but I think my first formula with `Lookup` covers all `Vlookup` functionality