# Get latest date of a bill payment

Tags: excel, indexing, max, vlookup

Excel is kicking my dogged butt on a problem here.

My situation is I want to get the latest payment date of a certain bill. Here is some example data from my table:

```
Date          Bill Type      Amount
==========    ===========    =======
2016-01-01    Hydro          $50.00
2016-01-04    Mortgage       $400.00
2016-02-04    Mortgage       $400.00
2016-03-04    Mortgage       $400.00
2016-04-01    Hydro          $50.00
2016-04-04    Mortgage       $400.00
```

So, say I need to find my latest mortgage payment date, I need a function that will return 2016-04-04. And I need to do this for a series of bills: Hydro, Electricity, Heat, Security, etc. What determines which bill I want to see? A table on another worksheet. Here's example data from this table:

```
Bill          Company    Account Number    Latest Payment
==========    =======    ==============    ==============
Heat          XYZ Inc.   123-456-789-0     2016-02-03
Hydro         ABC Inc.   234-567-890-1     2016-04-01
Mortgage      QRS Inc.   345-678-901-2     2016-04-04
```

And so on. That Latest Payment column would be where this mysterious formula goes.

I've been playing with various combinations of Vlookup, Max, Index, Match, etc. but always come up with an error message, #N/A, or #VALUE. Vlookup seems to work fine if the date column is to the right of the lookup column (Bill Type). But unfortunately it the table isn't laid out that way. I've also been searching high and low on Stackoverflow and Google and, though, some things look promising, there's always a tweak I can't seem to work my way around.

Can anyone help? Thanks, everyone!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23205575/find-last-match-in-column-using-built-in-functions-in-excel-vba).

Comment: @findwindow I would say no, as that question is looking at position in a list, where this question is looking for latest date...solution may be the same but the nuance in the question is slightly difference.  His latest date could be in the middle of the list instead of at top or bottom.

Comment: @ForwardEd actually, if you read the answer to the link, it's the same. Finding the last occurence of something in a list, not necessarily top or bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your provided table 1 is in a sheet named `Sheet1`, and that your header row is row 1 and actual data starts in row 2, then in the `Latest Payment` column, use this formula and copy down:

```
=MAX(INDEX((Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7=A2)*Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7,))
```

Adjust ranges to suit your actual data.  Format the cells to be a date format so that it shows a date instead of the date serial number.

Comment: it worked for me without having to reformat date.  I think the trick is the date has to be an excel date serial number and not a date stored as a string.

Comment: Hi all, for =MAX(INDEX((Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7=A2)*Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7,)) I got 0. I have to admit this whole thing is confusing me. :S I'm trying to (1) go into a table and find all values of a date that match a certain bill type and then (2) isolate the latest date. I've broken it down to INDEX and LOOKUP, but I'm still getting weird results such as 12 (the row number of the last entry in the table, not necessarily the latest) when I check the link given by findwindow, #REF, #VALUE, 0, or even just the first instance of the date. But I can't even break down the formula and make it work piece by piece

Comment: I should add that, for the formula given by tigeravatar, I did enter the proper ranges and sheet names.

Comment: Ok, with some rejigging, I got it to find the last (but not latest) entry, with this formula: INDEX('9220'!B3:B13,LOOKUP(2,1/('9220'!E3:E13=B52),ROW('9220'!E3:E13))-2). (As you can tell, my sheet is called 9220 and my table is A3 to J13 with the name of the bill in column E and the date in column B.) It's not the full solution, but it's a workable step.

Comment: @SteveG. I'm confused, why are you using lookup?  Are your dates actually text that looks like dates and not actually dates?  The formula as provided should return the latest date for a given criteria.

Comment: The dates are in a custom format: yyyy-mmm-dd. Does this not work? I guess that would be considered text. :/ Any way to get a date to show that format? The closest option I see is yyyy-mm-dd (ex. 2001-03-14, not 2001-Mar-14) so I switched to yyyy-mm-dd, but I still get 0 from entering =MAX(INDEX(('9220'!$E$3:$E$13=B57)*'9220'!$B$3:$B$13,)). Also I was using lookup just to tinker and see what could help.

Comment: @SteveG. That you're able to format them like that indicates they are actually dates and not text that looks like dates.  Are your dates in sheet `9220` column B?  And your criteria that you're looking for matches is in sheet `9220` column E? because that's what the formula is currently looking at.  Without being able to actually see your data, I can't really help further.