# index match with a max

Tags: excel, max

[image]

*sample data I would expect it to show in regards to Axle 1 900 as this is the most recent date

Hi I am having issues with getting my formula to work.

I cant figure out how to get it to bring back the most recent date look up information.

Below is my current code

```
    =INDEX('All Data'!$E$3:$E$6,MATCH(1,($H$5='All Data'!$D$3:$D$6)*($G$11='All Data'!$C$3:$C$6),0))
```

Thanks 
Paula

Comment: could you provide some sample data and what you expect the output to be?

Comment: @DanielGimenez I have updated my post to include an image of my data

Comment: What is in your F column? You mention it in the formula but we do not see the data. I expect you have 900 in your H5 and 1 in your G11. Right? And you would like your formula to return 26/8/2016. Right?

Comment: Moreover MATCH will return number between 1 and 4 or #N/A. So I do not get why you use with INDEX where are trying to get value from almost 190 values. This is one obvious mistake.

Comment: @V.K. it currently is displaying an answer of 799 where as I need it to return the value of 900 as this is the most recent date and the corresponding value displayed in column E

Comment: @V.K. I deleted a column to see if I could get another suggested fix to work I have updated my code to display this

Comment: OK, now it makes sense and I understand what you want to achieve. Before your data and your formula were not in sync. :)

Comment: Are your dates in column A always increasing?

Comment: Currently you are only looking at `Coach No.` and `Axle No.` and not taking the date into account at all.  Does your formula specifically need to match the Coach and Axle No.'s?  Or do you just need the first result that is the latest date?

Comment: @V.K. nope sadly they are not always increasing it could be random dates being entered

Comment: @tigeravatar I specifically need it to look at coach no and axel no and then match this to the latest date... this is where my main issue is coming in

Comment: @Paula: I have updated my answer to be able to cope with not-always-increasing dates.

Answer (score 1):

If your dates are always increasing, then you can find the last value with this: `{=INDEX('All Data'!$E$3:$E$6,MATCH(2,1/(($H$5='All Data'!$D$3:$D$6)*($G$11='All Data'!$C$3:$C$6))))}`

Note the number 2, operation 1/... and no 0 as the last argument in MATCH. The trick is described here: [find last match in column using built in functions in excel vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23205575/find-last-match-in-column-using-built-in-functions-in-excel-vba)

UPDATE: If your dates are not increasing, then you need to do it in two steps. First, find the maximum date (let's name the cell `MAX_DATE`): `{=MAX(($H$5='All Data'!$D$3:$D$6)*($G$11='All Data'!$C$3:$C$6)*($A$3:$A$6))}` and then find the combination matching values in columns C and D and also the maximum date `{=INDEX('All Data'!$E$3:$E$6,MATCH(1,($H$5='All Data'!$D$3:$D$6)*($G$11='All Data'!$C$3:$C$6)*(MAX_DATE='All Data'!$A$3:$A$6),0))}`.