# Find the last match from two columns

Tags: excel

The following question discusses how to find last match in a column:

[find last match in column using built in functions in excel vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23205575/find-last-match-in-column-using-built-in-functions-in-excel-vba#)

I need a way to find the last instance on an entry based on two columns.

[image]

So, find the last 'Item1' from column B and find the last '2 L' from column D. When both match, display the corresponding value from column C.

I tried using the AND function with the solution mentioned in the above questions but AND does not work with the arrays generated.

Any clues how I could get this done? Thank you!

PS: I need to do it without VBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the example you give:

`=LOOKUP(1,0/((B2:B6=F3)*(D2:D6=G3)),C2:C6)`

Ranges passed to such a construction should be kept to a minimum. Using entire column references, for example, would be a terrible idea.

Regards

Comment: Thank you! That works, and yes I ll try to keep the column reference short.