# LOOKUP formula to find last value in VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I want to convert a lookup formula into Worksheet function but it prompts `Type mismatch` error.

This formula working fine.

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(SalesDB!I6:I3005="FLOUR"),SalesDB!K6:K3005)
```

This prompts `Type mismatch` error

```
ActiveSheet.Range("Q9").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Lookup(2, 1 / (Sheets("SalesDB").Range("$I$6:$I$3005") = "FLOUR"), Sheets("SalesDB").Range("$K$6:$K$3005"))
```

I want to lookup last value from a column so `Vlookup` formula does not work on it. How can I solve the error?

Comment: Your formula looks like an array formula. You can't use array formulas in VBA.

Comment: @Variatus - you can, either using the `FormulaArray` property or the `Evaluate` method.

Comment: @SJR Yes, indeed. I didn't think of that.

Comment: This is not an array formula, This formula lookup the last value from a column.

Comment: @Adnan - see my updated answer. You can use Find with search order reversed to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ['trick' you are using with the `LOOKUP` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23205575/find-last-match-in-column-using-built-in-functions-in-excel) won't easily translate to VBA. You can use a simple `Find` method with the search order reversed (parameter `SearchDirection:=xlPrevious`) which will find the last match and then use the `Offset` function to go across the columns to retrieve the value you want.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    ActiveSheet.Range("Q9").Value = LastVlookup("FLOUR", Sheets("SalesDB").Range("$I$6:$K$3005"), 3)

End Sub

Function LastVlookup(varLookup As Variant, rngData As Range, lngOffset As Long) As Variant

    LastVlookup = rngData.Find( _
        What:=varLookup, _
        LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Offset(0, lngOffset - 1).Value

End Function
```

Comment: I want to lookup last value from a column so vlookup formula does not work on it. The first formula working OK but I just want to convert it into VBA code.