# Find last "non-empty" text match in column using built in functions in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The following question discusses to find last match in column

[find last match in column using built in functions in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23205575/find-last-match-in-column-using-built-in-functions-in-excel)

I need a way to find the last non empty value on an entry based on month columns.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gpnvg.jpg

So as per above Image,

I had used =LOOKUP(2,1/($A:$A=$D$3),$B:$B) this formula to get value for month but for Jan it showing correct but for Month Feb it showing Value 0 instead of ABS-143-002 because last value for Month Feb empty cell.

I tried too much but not getting perfect answer for this

Please, help me with this I need non empty last value from column B for selected month without using VBA.

Comment: Can you show up your formula? This LOOKUP is ok with numbers, but as far as I know will not work with strings as there is no "bigger" value.

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego Not so. `The values in lookup_vector can be text, numbers, or logical values.`  or errors, for that matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to check that `B:B` is not empty.

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(($A:$A=D3)*(LEN($B:$B)>0)),$B:$B)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You Very Much Sir for your Valuable Support :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

Column C (Cell C2): `=IF(B2<>"",IF(COUNTIF(C3:$C$15,A2),"",A2),"")`

Later drag for the column (If the last one is not C15, just custom)

On Column E (E3): `=VLOOKUP($D3,CHOOSE({2\1},$B$2:$B$15,$C$2:$C$15),2,0)`

So you can look up backwards. Just drag it down.

Hope it helps