# ARRAYFORMULA and COUNTA to count only up to current row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image: Here's an example of my sheet]

In row D, I would like to count the values of row E (COUNTA) but only up the the current row of the column.
I tried using ARRAYFORMULA and COUNTA and ROW, but from what I've read, COUNTA won't work with ARRAYFORMULA. What I get with this formula is the total COUNTA of the column returned for each row.

I need to automatically apply the formula to the rows (and new rows) so I had intended to use ARRAYFORMULA. However, I was also looking into QUERY functions as well to no avail. I think my solution might be in scripts, but I am not very confident with them yet.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(INDIRECT("E1:E"&ROW())))
```

Comment: I edited my post to include my need for auto-populating the formula to apply to all rows. This is why I initially used ARRAYFORMULA, but it seems to not work with COUNTA.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Turns out, I was right about the solution being an app script. Here's my code:

```
function myFunction() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  ss.getRange("D2").setFormula("=IF(ISBLANK($A2),,COUNTA(INDIRECT($F2)))");

  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  var downRange = ss.getRange(2, 4, lr-1);

  ss.getRange("D2").copyTo(downRange);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

D1:

```
 =ARRAYFORMULA({"What I Want";
  IF(ISBLANK(E2:LOOKUP(2,1/(E:E<>""),E:E)),,
    COUNTIFS(SEQUENCE(LOOKUP(2,1/(E:E<>""),SEQUENCE(2^20))-1),
        "<="&SEQUENCE(LOOKUP(2,1/(E:E<>""),SEQUENCE(2^20))-1),
    E2:LOOKUP(2,1/(E:E<>""),E:E),
        "<>"
    )
  )
})
```

#### Notes:

From the inside,

- `LOOKUP(2,1/(E:E<>""),E:E)` - `LOOKUP` provides the last empty range[<sup>1</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23205637/)
- `E2:LOOKUP(..)`  provides a range: `E2:E11` in this case. This syntax can be used to create dynamic ranges
- `LOOKUP(...,SEQUENCE(2^20))` provides last empty row number upto 2^20(~36k) rows
- `SEQUENCE(LOOKUP(...))` provides a sequence of numbers from 1 to last row.
- `SEQUENCE(), "<="&SEQUENCE()` inside `COUNTIFS` provides the logic for running total. First sequence creates a ascending number array(like 1,2,3...). Second sequence provides a ascending criteria array( like <=1,<=2,<=3,...). Each number in the number array is compared against all in the criteria array. For ex, When comparing `2`, two criterias are satisfied, (<=1 and <=2). So, for row 2, the count is 2(the count of all previous rows)
- `COUNT` rows IF the above condition is satisfied and  E:E is not empty ("<>")
- Empy the blanks with `IF(ISBLANK)`